# public VF pages in customer community

Tags: customer-community

Can I include in my customer community VF pages and make them public (accessible to people without login)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do it, but to achieve this you will need to give access to those VF pages to the Guest user profile.

For this go to "Manage Communities" and click on the link "Force.com". On this page you can give access to these VF pages to guest profile.